# Clear textareas onclick

Tags: javascript, html, button, textarea

I know this question has been asked before, but I am looking for a specific answer based on the code I'm providing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function insertText(name, text) { var elem = document.getElementById(name); elem.innerHTML += text; }
</script>

...

<img src="/images/text1.png" onclick="insertText('textbox1', 'Text to be displayed'); insertText('textbox2', 'Text to be displayed');">
<img src="/images/text2.png" onclick="insertText('textbox1', 'Text to be displayed'); insertText('textbox2', 'Text to be displayed');">
<img src="/images/clear.png" onclick="this.form.elements['textbox1'].value = ''; this.form.elements['textbox2'].value = '';">

...

<textarea id="textbox1" name="option1"></textarea>
<textarea id="textbox2" name="option2"></textarea>
```

It really doesn't get any more basic than this (and yes I relize there is basic html stuff missing, I stripped it down to show it better)

The click events work fine with the function call and append the text to the textarea.  The problem is when I click the 'clear' image, nothing happens.  I see many examples where people say this works, but it doesn't.  Nothing clears when I click the 'clear' button.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have a form somewhere?

Comment: `img` is not a "form element", it has not `form` property, not even if it was placed within a form.

Comment: Change this `<textarea name="textbox1"></textarea>`

Comment: This is true Teemu, however if that's the case then why do the buttons to add the text work fine?

Comment: @hex Yes there are working form tags present in the original

Comment: @user3715740 Because the function they call uses `document.getElementById()` to find textboxes.

Comment: Perhaps I should have left in the name fields.  This form submits and the names are already taken up for post methods...
UPDATE:  I changed the name to 'textbox1' and 'textbox2' and just put:
    <img src="/images/clear.png" onclick="document.getElementById('textbox1').value = ''; />

Just to test one of them, but the button does nothing...

Comment: @user3715740 Since this is an interesting question, you could consider changing the title to something more self-describing

Comment: UPDATE:  I stripped this down into its most basic form and it works...Not sure what is wrong with my original, I still have to try to break it down but ironically enough I couldn't get it to work in fiddle!

Comment: Heres the working version:
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function insertText(name, text) { var elem = document.getElementById(name); elem.value += text; }
function removeText(name) { document.getElementById(name).value= ""; }
</script>
<head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="post.html">
<img src="/images/lms.png" onclick="insertText('textbox1', 'Text!');" />
<img src="/images/clear.png" onclick="removeText('textbox1');" />
<textarea id="textbox1" required></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
onclick="document.getElementById['textbox1'].value = ''; document.getElementById['textbox2'].value = '';">
```

ID should be unique, so elements is not supported for search by ID

Comment: Thanks to everyone.  As it turns out, I had a function called function clear(name)
Apparently you can't call a fucntion 'clear' because once I changed that (to 'remoteText) it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.value`, just use `.innerHTML` again. I am assuming `this.form.elements['textbox1']` is the same as the `textbox1` you are changing with the `elem.innerHTML += text;`. If you use

```
this.form.elements['textbox2'].innerHTML = "";
```

it will give you the desired results.

However, you may want to switch to `value`. Switch all references to `.innerHTML` to `.value` and it will also work.

Comment: `img.form` does not exist and `textarea` can't have HTML : (.

Comment: Instead of using this.form just switch back to your original syntax:
document.getElementById('textbox1').innerHTML = '';

Comment: Well either I don't know how to code or this doesn't work :/  I tried this and also changed the code to make it really easy, but no dice

Comment: `elem.innerHTML += text; -> elem.value += text;`

`this.form.elements['textbox1'].value = ''; -> document.getElementById('textbox1').value = ''`

and the same for textbox2 code and it should work.

Comment: Thanks Derongan and others, but these changes aren't working.  No matter what I do, when I click that clear button, it does nothing, or at least nothing noticable.  There are also no errors in the full source code, so this is really puzzling!

Comment: .innerHTML doesn't always work, though, at least not for me. What did work consistently was .value.

Answer (score 1):

To change or update the contents of a `textarea` or `input` text field, you don't use the `innerHTML` property, you use the `value` property.

Answer (score 1):

`img` is not a "form element", it has not `form` property, not even if it was placed within a form.

If the `img` is a direct child of the form, you can do something like this:

```
<img src=".." onclick="this.parentElement.elements['textbox1'].value = ''; this.parentElement.elements['textbox2'].value = '';" />
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Vx4s/1/).

If it's not, use `document.getElementById` instead to refer textareas.

However, I'd suggest you to use proper eventhandling, for example [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Also `elem.innerHTML += text;` in `insertText()` may block the textareas from further programmatically edits. Use `value` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, in your fiddle, once cleared you can't add it in again...

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice the `innerHTML` in the copy-pasted function, it should be `value`. I've updated the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommed to use jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).load(function(){
    $("#insertText1").click(function(){
        $("#textbox1").val("Text to be displayed");
    });
    $("#insertText2").click(function(){
        $("#textbox2").val("Text to be displayed");
    });
    $("#insertTextClear").click(function(){
        $("#textbox1").val("");
        $("#textbox2").val("");
    });
});
</script>
...
<img src="/images/text1.png" id="insertText1">
<img src="/images/text2.png" id="insertText2">
<img src="/images/clear.png" id="insertTextClear">
...
<textarea id="textbox1" name="option1"></textarea>
<textarea id="textbox2" name="option2"></textarea>
```

Comment: Why use jQuery if it's just for clearing a `textarea`?